# Unable to select Microservices application option in jhipster 3.4.2

Tags: jhipster

Below is the environment setup I have,

- Windows 10
- Oracle VM VirtualBox - v5.0.20 r106931
- Docker Toolbox
- node --version v5.9.0
- jhipster v3.4.2

Problem/Issue
I have already started jipster registry, but I cannot select Microservice application or gateway after running "yo jhipster"

I have create a couple of application using v3.4.0 (also does not have Microservices application option). How do I enable v3.4.2 with Microservices application option ?

Regards
James

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you should use NodeJS LTS version as we recommend it. Consider using our devbox https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-devbox

Comment: Yes, use LTS, we're not testing the unstable versions

Comment: I tried into install jhipster-devbox and I need to install vagrant first, but I tried to get vagrant up, but it seems that there isnt vagrant box entry from https://atlas.hashicorp.com that supports Windows 10. Hope my understanding is right.

Comment: for this one => `vagrant init jhipster/jhipster-devbox`, it is referring to ubuntu/trusty64

Comment: I uninstall the previous nodejs and update nodejs LTS to 4.4.6, the problem on being unable to select microservices application option still persist.

Comment: ubuntu/trusty64 is the OS of the VM not your OS. I have no problem running it on WIndows 10: I just run: `chcp 1252`, then `vagrant init jhipster/jhipster-devbox` and finally `vagrant up`. Quite usual

Comment: Now both jhipster version can use microservices. thanks to Julien and Gael for your help and info. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special to do, my only guess is that you may have a `.yo-rc.json` file in the folder you ran `yo jhipster`. Try in an empty directory.

Comment: I notice that there could be 2 versions of jhipster in my environment eg c/Users/user (this is my home directory), this version in the home directory is 3.4.0. I also notice that if I run jhipster from d/Workspace/jhipster-apps, version 3.4.2 is used. My understanding is the .yo-rc.json file is only created in the empty folder after the completion of those questions during the run of "yo jhipster". What could be wrong here ?

Comment: Your understanding for .yo-rc.json file is correct but I'm confused but your other statements. What does it mean that jhipster is installed  in your home or in your workspace? generator-jhipster should be installed globally  by 'npm install -g` so in a node_modules sub folder of your node installation.